# MySQL where condition on alpha-numeric column

Tags: mysql, sql

My employee table has a column for work level containing values like 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A, 2B, & 2C.
Employee hierarchy is 2C > 2B > 2A > 1C > 1B > 1A.

Now if I write a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE work_level >= 1C
```

Would it return the rows containing only work levels 1C, 2A, 2B, 2C?

If not then how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will return the desired rows, but do remember to add an inverted comma to the where clause::

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE work_level >= '1C'
```

Comment: 'inverted comma'? That's a quote, not a comma of any sort.

Comment: @Marc B I had never seen this expression either, but "inverted comma" seems to be a synonym for "quotation mark" in British English... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_comma)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

Let us say you have some `work_level`s and input as defined below :

```
set @work_level1 = '25C';  
set @input_work_level1 = '1C';  

set @work_level2 = '2C';  
set @input_work_level2 = '15C';  

set @work_level3 = '2A';  
set @input_work_level3 = '1C';  

set @work_level4 = '2C';  
set @input_work_level4 = '15B';
```

Running the following query :

```
select   
 ( cast( left(@work_level1, length(@work_level1)-1) as unsigned )
   >=
   cast( left(@input_work_level1, length(@input_work_level1)-1) as unsigned )
 )
 and
 right(@work_level1, 1) <= right(@input_work_level1, 1)
 as '''25C'' >= ''1C''',

 ( cast( left(@work_level2, length(@work_level2)-1) as unsigned )
   >=
   cast( left(@input_work_level2, length(@input_work_level2)-1) as unsigned )
 )
 and
 right(@work_level2, 1) <= right(@input_work_level2, 1)
 as '''2C'' >= ''15C''',

 ( cast( left(@work_level3, length(@work_level3)-1) as unsigned )
   >=
   cast( left(@input_work_level3, length(@input_work_level3)-1) as unsigned )
 )
 and
 right(@work_level3, 1) <= right(@input_work_level3, 1)
 as '''2A'' >= ''1C''',

 ( cast( left(@work_level4, length(@work_level4)-1) as unsigned )
   >=
   cast( left(@input_work_level4, length(@input_work_level4)-1) as unsigned )
 )
 and
 right(@work_level4, 1) <= right(@input_work_level4, 1)
 as '''2C'' >= ''15B'''
;
```

would result :

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
| '25C' >= '1C' | '2C' >= '15C' | '2A' >= '1C' | '2C' >= '15B' |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
|             1 |             0 |            1 |             0 |
+---------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+
```